# Missing shared Library for Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, shared-libraries

What do I have to do to include an external library to my Android application?

I know, it's similar to a problem what I found here very often, but I **don't** want to use Google Maps API, I want to use another library, in this case it's *apache commons*.

I followed every step and compared them to different manuals or tutorials:

1. I imported 'commons-lang-2.4jar' to the libs-folder in my
   project,
2. I added this 'commons-lang-2.4jar' to the Referenced
   Libraries,
3. I added the use to the manifest-file:

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>`

But I get these popular errors:

Console:
`[2011-09-23 10:53:41 - TestProject] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`
`[2011-09-23 10:53:41 - TestProject] Please check logcat output for more details.`
`[2011-09-23 10:53:41 - TestProject] Launch canceled!`

LogCat:
`09-23 08:53:39.904: ERROR/PackageManager(71): Package test.project requires unavailable shared library org.apache.commons.lang; failing!`

In case of the problem with Google Maps API I know my emulator needs the API, so I would guess my emulator now needs this library? But no device would have it - so I need to include it?! (tried to check this library in properties "order and export" via eclipse, but no success)

Comment: you dont have to add the `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>`. This is only needed in case of google maps library. just make sure that apache commons is on your build path

Comment: so easy? thought I have missed something - but I have done too much? :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>`

This is only for Android Project Libraries not a plain old Jar file. Jar files will have their classes extracted and put into your apk by just including them in the build path.